# how to return a collection of currency rate related to query parameters in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have currencies table which holds all currencies. I create a route that tells laravel `please give me all currencies rate in query params`. The problem is it returns only the first param rate.
I want something like this:

```
{"usd":2, "gbp":2.3}
```

here is my code:

```
   **in query string**
    api/v3/getCurrencies?currency[]=GBP&currency[]=USD
   **in CurrenciesController.php**

   public function getByCurrencyName(Request $request) {
      $currencyCollection = collect();
   $currencies = collect($request->all());
      $currencies->each(function($currency) use ($currencyCollection) {
          $value = Currency::where('type', '=', $currency)->get();
          $currencyCollection->push($currency, $value);
      });
      return $currencyCollection;
   }
```

Comment: Why not just `return Currency::whereIn('type', $request->all())->pluck('value');`?

Comment: (Also, if `usd` and `gbp` are in your request, but `USD` and `GBP` are in your database, as in your example URL and output, you may have a case sensitivity issue.)